# HowTo mark Trailhead module as read?

Tags: lightning-apps, trailhead

Im currently working on [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/lex_implementation_customization/lex_implementation_customization_apps) Trailhead module and have just noticed their is no challenge at the end.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how this module gets marked as 'read'? I am logged into my Developer Environment and Trailhead is connected.

Comment: you cannot mark is as 'read', I think it is incomplete from Salesforce side. But I have got the badge completed.

Comment: Salesforce have stated 'You can still earn points by marking the unit as read'. Why would they tell their users this and not allow them to mark it as read?

Comment: It has been raised on the SF Trailhead forum too https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Trailhead&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=9060G000000XdHHQA0

Comment: Cheers @DaveHumm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Salesforce success community for Trailhead](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009Nek) it has been acknowledged as a bug and due for a fix by 1 November.

[image]

Salesforce now have fixed it and I have tested that it works successfully.

[image]